# HttpHandler instance and HttpApplication object - does the latter...?

Tags: c#, asp.net, httphandler, ihttphandler

A Book showed an example where ( when using IIS7 ) the following module was configured such that it would be used by any web application ( even by non-asp.net apps ) running on a web site. But:

1. if this module is invoked for non-asp.net application, then how or why would HttpApplication object still be created, since non-asp.net apps don’t run in the context of CLR ( and thus Asp.Net runtime also won’t run )?
2. Assuming `HttpApplication` object is also created for non-asp.net apps, why then does the code inside Init() event handler have to check for whether `HttpApplication` object actually exists? Why wouldn’t it exist? Isn’t this  `HttpApplication` object which actually instantiates  Http module instance?

Here is Http handler:

```
public class SimpleSqlLogging : IHttpModule
{
  private HttpApplication _CurrentApplication;

  public void Dispose()
  {
      _CurrentApplication = null;
  }

  public void Init(HttpApplication context)
  {
      // Attach to the incoming request event
      _CurrentApplication = context;

      if (context != null)
      {
          context.BeginRequest += new EventHandler(context_BeginRequest);
      }
  }

  void context_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
  { ... }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In IIS7 an application in app pool running with the integrated pipeline is always a .NET application.  The code is just being defensive.

Answer (score 0):

A link about HttpHander : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc188942.aspx

Comment: Please don't just provide links for your answers.